# Realizar loop entre um loop existente SimpleXML Tag de Fotos

Tags: php, loop, foreach, for, simplexml

Como eu converto isso (que só me trás a primeira foto)

```
//corrige foto
$enderecofoto = $xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->foto;
$nomeeextensao = preg_replace("(^.*\/(.*)\$)", "$1$2",$enderecofoto);
$removenomeeextensao = str_replace($nomeeextensao, "", $enderecofoto);
$nomefoto = substr($nomeeextensao, 0 , (strrpos($nomeeextensao, ".")));
//remove antiga tag antes de adicionar a nova, para evitar remoção de ambas
unset($xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->foto);
$foto = $xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->addChild('foto');
$foto->addAttribute('path', $removenomeeextensao);
$foto->addAttribute('arquivo', $nomeeextensao);
$foto->addAttribute('titulo', $nomefoto);
```

Em um loop?

Meu script é basicamente isso, e essa "conversão" ficaria ali:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("feed.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($xml); $i++) {
@@@@AQUI@@@@
}
echo $xml->asXML();
$xml->asXML('xml.xml');
```

O Loop deve resultar em:

```
<fotos>
<foto path="http://localhost:8090/images/" arquivo="1.jpg" titulo="1"/>
<foto path="http://localhost:8090/images/" arquivo="2.jpg" titulo="2"/>
<foto path="http://localhost:8090/images/" arquivo="3.jpg" titulo="3"/>
</fotos>
```

Ao invés de (o que está atualmente):

```
<fotos>
<foto path="http://localhost:8090/images/" arquivo="1.jpg" titulo="1"/>
</fotos>
```

O que me dizem?

Olhando no [StackOverflow eu achei isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671936/php-simplexml-and-arrays):

```
foreach($xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->foto as $foto) { 
  if(isset($xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->foto)) {
    $fotos = array();
    foreach ($xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->foto as $foto) {
      $fotos[] = "$foto"; 
      // or you could use, I believe: $fotos[] = $foto[0] 
    }
  } 
  else $fotos = "";
  var_dump($fotos); 
  echo "<hr />"; 
}
```

Mas como eu faço esse foreach usar as minhas configurações? Para que uma nova tag XML receba os dados da forma como foi setado na config que fiz lá em cima?

--------------EDIT

```
    foreach($xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->foto as $foto) { 
      if(isset($xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->foto)) {
        $fotos = array();
        foreach ($xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->foto as $foto) {
          $fotos[] = "$foto"; 
          $nomeeextensao = preg_replace("(^.*\/(.*)\$)", "$1$2",$foto);
          $removenomeeextensao = str_replace($nomeeextensao, "", $foto);
          $nomefoto = substr($nomeeextensao, 0 , (strrpos($nomeeextensao, ".")));
          $fotoxml = $xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->addChild('foto');
          $fotoxml->addAttribute('path', $removenomeeextensao);
          $fotoxml->addAttribute('arquivo', $nomeeextensao);
          $fotoxml->addAttribute('titulo', $nomefoto);
        }
      } 
      else $fotos = "";
      var_dump($fotos); 
      echo "<hr />"

; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu desenvolvi um webservice pra integração dos imóveis da nossa imobiliária com o aplicativo beview acho que vc consegue entender o que estou fazendo e adaptar no seu, ficou assim:

```
$result = mysql_query(sua query);

$registros = mysql_num_rows($result);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $fotos = explode(',', $row['fotos']);
                    $ord = 2;
                    foreach ($fotos as $foto){
                    $xml .="<arquivo>\n";
                        $xml .="<titulo>Foto Galeria</titulo>\n";
                        $xml .="<url>http://*******.com/cpanel/fotos/$row[id_imovel]/$foto</url>\n";
                        $xml .="<tipo>Foto</tipo>\n";
                        $xml .="<ordem>".$ord++."</ordem>\n";
                        $xml .="<categoria>Foto do Empreendimento</categoria>\n";
                    $xml .="</arquivo>\n";
}
```

Enquanto encontrar fotos, vai exibindo o link dentro da

Comment: Bem interessante, no seu caso você utilizou uma query mysql como array.
Vou tentar utilizar essa ideia do foreach e modificar a minha.
Valeu ai :D

Comment: É.... infelizmente não está dando certo.... :(

Comment: @Diego.  Qual o erro que retornou para vc?

Comment: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes). Ou execution time.... 90 seconds.

Vou editar o tópico principal com o código que usei.

Comment: Existe algo relacionado ao seu erro nesse link:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml). Porém, poste o código que você esta executando.

Comment: Já postei, está no EDIT no post principal. Dá uma olhada.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->foto as $foto) { 
    $fotos = array();
    $nomeeextensao = preg_replace("(^.*\/(.*)\$)", "$1$2",$foto);
    $removenomeeextensao = str_replace($nomeeextensao, "",$foto);
    $nomefoto = substr((string)$nomeeextensao, 0 , (strrpos((string)$nomeeextensao, ".")));
    $fotoxml = $xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->addChild('fotomudar');
    $fotoxml->addAttribute('path', (string)$removenomeeextensao);
    $fotoxml->addAttribute('arquivo', (string)$nomeeextensao);
    $fotoxml->addAttribute('titulo',(string) $nomefoto);
}
unset($xml->imovel[$i]->fotos->foto);
```

Consegui :D
Agora só usar um str_replace via file_get_content e mudar de fotomudar para foto, já que tive que dar unset ainda no simplexml.